# Python histogram-like plot with online data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have something like this:

```py
while *receiving_data*:
    for i in range(numBands):
        t1 = time.time()
        *processing_data*
        filt_time += time.time() - t1

        t2 = time.time()
        *processing_data*
        ent_time += time.time() - t2
```

I have to plot `filt_time` and `ent_time` in an histogram-like plot while receiving the data. So I need to plot these two values multiple times during the execution in order to have a visual representation of all these time values.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I like using [boost-histogram](https://boost-histogram.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

You would create and fill a histogram with 100 bins between timestamps `start_time` and `end_time` with:

```py
import boost_histogram as bh
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hist = bh.Histogram(bh.axis.Regular(100, start_time, end_time))
for ...:  # your loop
    hist.fill(filt_time)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(hist.axes[0].centers, hist.view(), width=hist.axes[0].widths)
fig.savefig("hist.pdf")
```

You find more examples in the [boost-histogram documentation](https://boost-histogram.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/BoostHistogramHandsOn.html).